# Teamcity REST URL for getting tags

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to get the url to access the tags on a build

we're running TeamCity 6.0.2

so far I can get to the build xml with

```
http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt12/builds/number:1.0.0.990
```

but adding /tags to the end won't give me just the tags xml

I've gone thru the [REST documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) but haven't found a combination that worked

The end goal is to PUT tags onto a specific build

**UPDATE:**

you have to specify the buildType in the  bit of the url. here's the one that works

```
http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:bt12,number:1.0.0.990/tags
```

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question byt what is tags in terms of TeamCity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misread the spec. The /tags is only allowed for one specific build and therefor I guess the /tags cannot be used on /buildTypes

Can you try this, assuming the id:bt12 gives you a specific build...

```
http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:bt12/tags/
```

Comment: Thanks, that url is wrong but you had the right idea, I posted the url that worked above